# operations on xml results returning 0

Tags: php

I was having trouble with my main page so I made a test page to find the problem. I'm grabbing hours played on games through an XML and any games that are played more than .1 but less than 1 hour I am trying to multiply by 60.

It it catching the numbers but it is returning 0 for them. Anything greater than 1 isn't going through the if as it is supposed to.

Why isn't it correctly doing the operation? How can I fix this?

```
$games = $gamespage->games;
$hoursplayed = 0;

    foreach($games->game as $game)
    {
    $hoursplayed = $game->hoursOnRecord;
    if ($hoursplayed < 1 && $hoursplayed >= .1) {
    $hoursplayed = $hoursplayed * 60; }
    echo $game->name, "<br />";
    echo $hoursplayed, "<br /><br />";
    }
```

Comment: What is `$gamespage`? A `SimpleXMLElement`?

Comment: $gamespage = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/id/jessejackson/games?xml=1");

Answer (score 1):

You might need to [cast](http://de.php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php) the values first, otherwise those are objects and you can not multiply objects in PHP:

```
$hoursplayed = 0;

foreach ($gamespage->games->game as $game)
{
    $hoursplayed = (float) $game->hoursOnRecord;
    if ($hoursplayed < 1 && $hoursplayed >= .1) 
    {
         $hoursplayed = $hoursplayed * 60; 
    }
    echo $game->name, "<br />", $hoursplayed, "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: It does work for me. I tried with the URL you have added in the comment above. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/haHmLL